# C# download a file from a URL without extension

Tags: c#, file

I want to get data from a site by download a web page, but when i put this link "http:\www.championcounter.com\Jinx" as a parameter of this code:

```
string url = "http:\\www.championcounter.com\Jinx";
string nome = "C:\Temp\data.dat";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(url, nome );
```

it give me this error:

```
System.UriFormatException: URI non valido: impossibile determinare il formato dell'URI.
in System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
in System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
in LoLCounter.Form.download(String url, String nome) in   c:\users\filippo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LoLCounter\LoLCounter\Form1.cs:riga 39
```

I think it's because it dosen't find the website because in the url don't have any extension

Comment: I think you got dinged because the question isn't specific enough.  Can you tell us more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Pisi in url try use `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: @Sakura thank you, now it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Net;
```

You can use:

```
var url = "http://www.championcounter.com/Jinx";

var textFromFile = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url); // get as string

(new WebClient()).DownloadFile(url, "D:\\pathToFile"); // or save to file
```

Comment: @Pisi in url try use `/` instead of `\\`